# Leaflet double map

Tags: leaflet

I've got a problem reguarding map tiles of leaflet:
when I zoom out, while loading you can clearly see there's another map under the tile I've selected, does anyone know how to possibly fix this?

[image]

Here's my code to generate the map:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([46.681364, 11.129706], 5);
L.tileLayer('https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth_dark/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    minZoom: 4,
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);
map.setMaxBounds([[-90,-180],[90,180]]);
<div id="map" class="leaflet-container leaflet-touch leaflet-fade-anim leaflet-grab leaflet-touch-drag leaflet-touch-zoom" tabindex="0" style="position: relative;top:0%; outline: none;width:100%;height:88%"><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-map-pane" style="transform: translate3d(235px, -53px, 0px);"><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tile-pane"><div class="leaflet-layer " style="z-index: 1; opacity: 1;"><div class="leaflet-tile-container leaflet-zoom-animated" style="z-index: 16; transform: translate3d(66px, 244px, 0px) scale(0.25);"></div><div class="leaflet-tile-container leaflet-zoom-animated" style="z-index: 18; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1);"></div></div></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-shadow-pane"></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-overlay-pane"></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane"></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tooltip-pane"></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-popup-pane"></div><div class="leaflet-proxy leaflet-zoom-animated" style="transform: translate3d(16365px, 10834px, 0px) scale(64);"></div></div><div class="leaflet-control-container"><div class="leaflet-top leaflet-left"><div class="leaflet-control-zoom leaflet-bar leaflet-control"><a class="leaflet-control-zoom-in" href="#" title="Zoom in" role="button" aria-label="Zoom in">+</a><a class="leaflet-control-zoom-out" href="#" title="Zoom out" role="button" aria-label="Zoom out">−</a></div></div><div class="leaflet-top leaflet-right"></div><div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-left"></div><div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-right"><div class="leaflet-control-attribution leaflet-control"><a href="https://leafletjs.com" title="A JS library for interactive maps">Leaflet</a> | © <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors</div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: This can't be your full code, you add somewhere else a second tileLayer

Comment: This is not the full code but it's the relevant one, I don't mention tiles in any other part of the code, I updated the code anyway.

Comment: [Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please.

Comment: You add somewhere other tiles, else your problem would not be happening. Maybe you add the tiles in a other function / javscript file. You can look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/27ojmnd8/), only the satelite tiles are loaded. Please create a running example

Comment: I've figured out what the problem was, basically in the html there were some images with "presentation" role. I added that line since I copied it to add the copyright section